# Creating a horizontal line between span and paragraph with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Is there a way that I can have a horizontal line between the span and paragraph. The line should have the same width as the paragraph. **How can I accpomplish this?**
I can't use a div because then it will be recognized as a flex item and it will put next to the paragraph.

If you need any further information. Just let me know.

**rentout.html.erb**

```
<div class="vorteil_wrapper">
    <div class="rentout_content_left">
        <p class="rentout_paragraph">
            <span class="rentout_heading">Erstellung eines professionellen Inserats</span></br>
            Wir besuchen Ihre Unterkunft und erstellen professionelle Fotos und Videos,
            welche nach der Bearbeitung für Ihr Inserat auf unserer Internetseite 
            genutzt werden. Darüber hinaus verfassen wir eine hochwertige Beschreibung
            und Präsentation Ihrer Unterkunft, welche die Highlights sowie die
            Atmosphäre Ihrer Unterkunft in Vordergrund setzt.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="rentout_picture_right">
        <%= image_tag("inserat.png", alt: "inserat", :class => "inserat") %>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="vorteil_wrapper_reverse">
    <div class="rentout_content_right">
        <p class="rentout_paragraph">
            <span class="rentout_heading">Responsive Webdesign</span></br>
            Wussten Sie das 65% aller Internet Nutzer ein Handy zum Surfen benutzen!
            Ihr zukünftiges Inserat wird auf unserer Seite optimal auf allen Geräten
            angezeigt, um somit die Benutzerfreundlichkeit und die Umsatzrate zu
            steigern.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="rentout_picture_left">
        <%= image_tag("responsive_webdesign.png", alt: "responsive webdesign", :class => "responsive_webdesign") %>
    </div>
</div>
```

**application.scss**

```
.vorteil_wrapper {
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.vorteil_wrapper_reverse {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.rentout_content_left {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 30px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.rentout_content_right {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 30px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.rentout_heading {
  font: 28px Raleway-Medium, sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-color: red;
}

.rentout_paragraph {
  text-align: justify;
  font: 18px Raleway-Regular, sans-serif;
}
```

This here is trying to solve the problem with position: absolute. The issue is that every heading starts on a different height because the elements(paragraph/span) inside the div(rentout_content_left/rentout_content_right) are centered and the number of characters in every paragraph and span vary.

```css
.rentout_wrapper {
  max-width: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.vorteil_wrapper {
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  position: relative;
}
.vorteil_wrapper_reverse {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
.rentout_content_left {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 30px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.rentout_content_right {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 30px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.rentout_heading {
  font: 28px Raleway-Medium, sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.rentout_heading::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -5px;
  width: 100%
}
.rentout_paragraph {
  text-align: justify;
  font: 18px Raleway-Regular, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="rentout_wrapper">
  <div class="vorteil_wrapper">
    <div class="rentout_content_left">
      <p class="rentout_paragraph">
        <span class="rentout_heading">Erstellung eines professionellen Inserats</span>
        </br>
        Wir besuchen Ihre Unterkunft und erstellen professionelle Fotos und Videos, welche nach der Bearbeitung für Ihr Inserat auf unserer Internetseite genutzt werden. Darüber hinaus verfassen wir eine hochwertige Beschreibung und Präsentation Ihrer Unterkunft,
        welche die Highlights sowie die Atmosphäre Ihrer Unterkunft in Vordergrund setzt.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="rentout_picture_right">
      <img src="//lorempixel.com/200/192">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="vorteil_wrapper_reverse">
    <div class="rentout_content_right">
      <p class="rentout_paragraph">
        <span class="rentout_heading">Responsive Webdesign</span>
        </br>
        Wussten Sie das 65% aller Internet Nutzer ein Handy zum Surfen benutzen! Ihr zukünftiges Inserat wird auf unserer Seite optimal auf allen Geräten angezeigt, um somit die Benutzerfreundlichkeit und die Umsatzrate zu steigern.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="rentout_picture_left">
      <img src="//lorempixel.com/200/192">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Clearly this should be a div with a heading and paragraph not a paragraph and span. You might want to think about reformatting your structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pseudo element `::after` in your `span`

**Note**: `</br>` is invalid,  either you use `<br>`, `<br/>` or `<br />`

```css
.vorteil_wrapper {
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.vorteil_wrapper_reverse {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
.rentout_content_left {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 30px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.rentout_content_right {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 30px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.rentout_heading {
  font: 28px Raleway-Medium, sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  display: block;
  position: relative
}
.rentout_heading::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -5px;
  width: 100%
}
.rentout_paragraph {
  text-align: justify;
  font: 18px Raleway-Regular, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="vorteil_wrapper">
  <div class="rentout_content_left">
    <p class="rentout_paragraph">
      <span class="rentout_heading">Erstellung eines professionellen Inserats</span>
      <br />
      Wir besuchen Ihre Unterkunft und erstellen professionelle Fotos und Videos, welche nach der Bearbeitung für Ihr Inserat auf unserer Internetseite genutzt werden. Darüber hinaus verfassen wir eine hochwertige Beschreibung und Präsentation Ihrer Unterkunft,
      welche die Highlights sowie die Atmosphäre Ihrer Unterkunft in Vordergrund setzt.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="rentout_picture_right">
    <img src="//lorempixel.com/200/200">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="vorteil_wrapper_reverse">
  <div class="rentout_content_right">
    <p class="rentout_paragraph">
      <span class="rentout_heading">Responsive Webdesign</span>
      <br />
      Wussten Sie das 65% aller Internet Nutzer ein Handy zum Surfen benutzen! Ihr zukünftiges Inserat wird auf unserer Seite optimal auf allen Geräten angezeigt, um somit die Benutzerfreundlichkeit und die Umsatzrate zu steigern.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="rentout_picture_left">
   <img src="//lorempixel.com/200/200">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually you are right with the <br> but for some reason it also works this way with </br> as u can see in the picture ;)
Thanks for trying but the line is invisible with your suggestion. If I have to do it with position: absolute and width: 100% I also have to make the wrapper position relative and even then It looks quite messy...

Comment: quite messy?? it works fine here. messy where?? show your snippet

Comment: I have added a snippet to my question ;)

Comment: did you take at least a close look at `.rentout_heading {
  font: 28px Raleway-Medium, sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  display: block;
  position: relative
}`  in my answer?? Because you did not update that. you need to add `position:relative` and change `inline-block` to `block`

Comment: OMG sorry for my blindness this was embarrassing! Thanks allot!

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following solution using `::after` on class `.rentout_heading`:

```css
.vorteil_wrapper {
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.vorteil_wrapper_reverse {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
.rentout_content_left {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 30px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.rentout_content_right {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 30px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.rentout_heading {
  font: 28px Raleway-Medium, sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration-color: red;
  width:100%;
}
.rentout_heading::after {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  border:1px solid red;
}
.rentout_paragraph {
  text-align: justify;
  font: 18px Raleway-Regular, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="vorteil_wrapper">
  <div class="rentout_content_left">
    <p class="rentout_paragraph">
      <span class="rentout_heading">Erstellung eines professionellen Inserats</span></br>
  Wir besuchen Ihre Unterkunft und erstellen professionelle Fotos und Videos,
  welche nach der Bearbeitung für Ihr Inserat auf unserer Internetseite 
  genutzt werden. Darüber hinaus verfassen wir eine hochwertige Beschreibung
  und Präsentation Ihrer Unterkunft, welche die Highlights sowie die
  Atmosphäre Ihrer Unterkunft in Vordergrund setzt.
  </p>
</div>
<div class="rentout_picture_right">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"/>
</div>
</div>

<div class="vorteil_wrapper_reverse">
  <div class="rentout_content_right">
    <p class="rentout_paragraph">
      <span class="rentout_heading">Responsive Webdesign</span></br>
  Wussten Sie das 65% aller Internet Nutzer ein Handy zum Surfen benutzen!
  Ihr zukünftiges Inserat wird auf unserer Seite optimal auf allen Geräten
  angezeigt, um somit die Benutzerfreundlichkeit und die Umsatzrate zu
  steigern.
  </p>
</div>
<div class="rentout_picture_left">
<img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"/>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This actually gives me only an underline underneath the heading. The line has not the width of the paragraph but thanks for trying. ;)

Comment: @trickydiddy - the line has the width of the paragraph. It think you forgot to set the `width:100%` to the `<span>` on your code? See the snippet here and inspect...

Comment: Yeah you are right! Thanks both answers are right but unfortunately I can only choose one... :/